# Is there a C#/.NET equivalent for the JVM's JMC+JFR for continuous profiling in production?

Tags: c#, .net, profiling, jmc, jfr

[Java Flight Recorder (JFR)](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/about.htm#JFRUH170) coupled with [JDK Mission Control](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk-mission-control.html) provides an excellent platform for [continuous/always-on profiling in production](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/cotinuous-profiling-production/).

Is there an analogous offering for C#/.NET (Core)? I read about [EventCounters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters) but those only seem to be a subset, and don't provide a live stack trace hotspot view.